# How to use spread operator in <script setup> Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  const {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...h} = useTest(); // useTest() return a lot of fields;
</script>
```

I don't want to list all the fields;

How to use spread operator like this: `...useTest()`;

Is the only way to add a `<script>` tag?

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import { useTest } from '.'
  export default {
    setup(){
      return {
        ...useTest(),
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not assign it to a `const`? Then you also have some namespacing which makes readability easier: `const myNamespace = useTest()` and in the template you can refer to it with `myNamespace.a`

Comment: I agree with Thomas. If you don't want to destructure then let `useTest()` return object or array and access value by `key` or `index` whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to move useTest in separate module (e.g. useTest.js) where you can declare all your exports. So in your .vue file you can do something like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import * as useTest from './useTest.js'

  // and use it further like so:
  useTest.a
  useTest.b
</script>
```